# Dynamic Libraries with generic type functions [c++]

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, shared-libraries

Last day's I was trying to do this in c++:

Let's say I have a function `foo(arg1, arg2)`, one client and one server.
`arg1` can be any type, `arg2` can be any type and `foo` can return any type of data. Function `foo` always has two arguments.

I want the client to take as an input this function(for example):

```
foo(arg1,arg2){

    if(arg1<arg2){
       return 1;
    }else{
       return 5.3;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and then this function to be transferred and executed on the server.

I tried to build dynamic library with this function inside with templates. However templates are not supported with `extern "C"`.
The library that i'm try to export is this:

```
#include < iostream >

  extern "C" {
    template < typename N >
      N testFunc(char * arg) {
        N test = 5;
        std::cout << "Executed| arg is:" << arg << std::endl;
        return test;

      }
  }
```

Then I tried to compile with the following commands :

 g++ -Wall -fPIC -c lib.cpp 
g++ -shared -o lib.so lib.o

So any idea how can I implement this?

I know this is not secure but its only for educational purposes.

Comment: c doesn't have template types. Also what compiler are you using? g++ well supports to export template functions from a shared library.

Comment: What do you mean by transfer the function? There isn't any standard way to serialize functions and send them over a network. Are you talking about creating a Remote Procedure Call library?

Comment: In most RPC implementations, you compile the function on the server and link it with an RPC wrapper to create the server. On the client you create a stub function that serializes the parameters and sends the call to the server.

Comment: @Barman I think on Remote Procedure calling the server allready knows the function. On my example I want the client to send the function, as it changes.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I tried with g++ and it throws me error

Comment: @NikosGrasidis May be you could give us a more concise (and syntactically correct) example of what exactly you tried to do.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have edited my post and I added how I am trying to compile

Answer (score 1):

If we make some simplifying assumptions, it's not too bad: let's imagine that the function you want to send and execute remotely takes no arguments and returns no value. Then you can do the following (working example below):

1. Send the source string to the server.
2. On the server, invoke gcc to compile the string, much as you described in your question.
3. Load the shared object and then call the function.

Now, this can be extended to the case you want with a bit more work: when the client sends the function, the server holds on to it for later use. Later the client sends a string containing the call to the function (including arguments) as a C++ string. The server appends the call string to the bottom of the function string and then compiles and runs the whole string as shown here. In this model, the function code can indeed be a template and the call string can contain any arguments for which type deduction would work. The downside is that you would be compiling the function each time. Depending on how trivial or time-intensive the function's runtime is, this may or may not be a problem for you. There are of course many many ways to do all this better, but I hope this serves as a starting point for you.

```
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <cstdio> 
#include <string> 
#include <cassert> 
#include <dlfcn.h> 


// Compile this with: g++ test.cpp -ldl 

// Utility: check various calls below and bail out if bad.
int check(int line, int ret, int err = -1)
{
  if (ret == err)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "on line %d: ", line);
    perror("");
    abort();
  }
  return ret;
}


#define CHECK(X, ...) check(__LINE__, X, ##__VA_ARGS__) 


// Common ipv4 address used by both client and server. 
struct sockaddr_in addr{};

// This runs the client's part.
int client_main()
{
  usleep(100000); // delay to give the server a chance to start. 

  // Connect to the server
  auto sock = CHECK(socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0));
  CHECK(connect(sock, (sockaddr*) &addr, sizeof(addr)));

  // This is the function to be remotely executed.
  std::string msg = R"( 
    #include <cstdio> 

    template <class T> 
    void remote_function(T arg1, T arg2) 
    { 
      if (arg1 < arg2) 
        printf("less\n"); 
      else 
        printf("more\n");   
    } 

    // ---- portion below can be sent separately and appended by server later ----- 

    extern "C" void runit() 
    { 
      remote_function(100, 1000); 
    } 

  )";

  // Send the source
  write(sock, msg.c_str(), msg.size());
  close(sock);

  // Client is done
  return 0;
}

// This is the server's part.
int server_main()
{
  // Listen for incoming connection from client
  auto sock = CHECK(socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0));
  CHECK(bind(sock, (sockaddr*) &addr, sizeof(addr)));
  CHECK(listen(sock, 1));
  struct sockaddr_in peer;
  socklen_t peer_sz = sizeof(peer);
  auto conn = CHECK(accept(sock, (sockaddr*) &peer, &peer_sz));

  // Read the source code from the client
  constexpr size_t maxSize = 1024 * 1024;
  std::string source(maxSize, 0);
  auto sz = CHECK(read(conn, &source[0], maxSize));
  source.resize(sz);
  printf("server got:%s\n", source.c_str());

  // Compile it
  auto gcc = popen("/usr/bin/g++ -o /tmp/_test.so -fPIC -shared -xc++ -", "w");
  assert(gcc);
  CHECK(fwrite(&source[0], 1, source.size(), gcc));
  auto ret = CHECK(pclose(gcc));
  if (ret == 0)
    printf("compiled!\n");
  else
    abort();

  // Load the compiled library
  auto lib = dlopen("/tmp/_test.so", RTLD_LOCAL | RTLD_NOW);
  assert(lib);

  // Run the function
  void (*fun)();
  * (void**) &fun = dlsym(lib, "runit");
  assert(fun);
  (*fun)();

  // Finished
  dlclose(lib);
  return 0;
}



int main()
{
  // Set up address both client and server use to communicate. 
  addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_LOOPBACK);
  addr.sin_port = htons(3333); // some arbitrary port. 

  if (fork())
    return server_main();
  else
    return client_main();
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting answer, +1 for effort. Am not sure how practical it is, though. This is probably not how C++ is meant to be used, nor am I sure that it would work if the client and server differed in CPU architecture and/or ABI format.

Comment: @thb, in my proposed solution, the client does not ever compile the code, nor run it. So the only architecture/ABI is the one on the server and since the end-user's function is compiled on the server, it's all consistent. The client could run on a totally different hardware or OS (the example client code I listed above would change appropriately of course).

Comment: @AlwaysConfused I have tested your code and seems to be doing what I wanted to. Any way to get the return value of the functions. I think this is hard as we do not know the type of function the user will send,

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to send the two objects to the server. You must also tell the server how to compare the two objects.

For example, suppose that I have a client and you have the server. Suppose that I have defined a type `Country` on my client. Suppose that the expression `netherlands < germany` evaluates true because I have defined `operator<(const Country&, const Country&)` to compare *land areas.* The Netherlands cover less land than does Germany, so `netherlands < germany == true`, right?

The trouble is that your server does not know what a `Country` is, nor how to compare two objects of that type.

Even if your server did know about `Country`, I could always come up with another type the server did not know. Therefore, unforutnately, unless I have misunderstood your question, I do not believe that there exists a straightforward way to do what you want.

Comment: I just wanted to do something similar to apache spark. Where the master sends a map function to the workers, and workers execute the map function. I know that is scala there are no types. But I really find it weird that this can't be implemented in c++

Comment: I am unfamiliar with scala and apache spark. Could they handle my `Country` example? It would seem to me that, for a type unknown to the server, the semantics of `<` comparison would need to be communicated from client to server somehow. But maybe I am missing something.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, I didn't think about that, however I just want the simple scenario. Given the simple data types and operators. Is it possible to do that.

Comment: I see. That's not easy, is it? Your problem is that C++ lets the local implementation decide how to represent a type. What if your server's `char` is signed and `long` is 64 bits while my client's `char` is unsigned and `long` is 32 bits? Moreover, even [`std::type_info::name()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name)—though it returns a plaintext string suitable for transmission over the network—lets the implementation choose the string it returns.

Comment: All I can think to do is to establish a predetermined set of types to be recognized and to specify the type by transmitting an enum defined by you. Alternately, since Boost libraries are widely used, would [this](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) help?